# Google sheets dynamic Forecast on Query gives #Value Error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, forecast

I'm trying to use a dynamic Forecast formula on a Query in Google sheets and it gives the following # VALUE Error:

> "*Error Function FORECAST parameter 1 expects number values. But
>   'QUERY ALL ORDERS date' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.*"

However, it gives a result, sees the images. I need some help to perfect the outcome without the `#VALUE` Error.

The Query is as follows:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/............/edit#gid=.......","query!A:B"), "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2), COUNT(Col2) WHERE Col1 IS NOT null GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 ASC")
```

The Dynamic Forecast filter is as follows:

```
=ArrayFormula(FORECAST(filter(A2:A,(N(B2:B)=0)*(A2:A>0)),filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""),filter(A2:A,B2:B<>"")))
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Do I need to format the Query? Change the Forecast formula?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FORECAST(FILTER(DATEVALUE(A2:A), (N(B2:B)=0)*(A2:A>0)), 
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""), FILTER(A2:A, B2:B<>"")))
```

the error means that those dates in column A are most likely formatted as Plain text instead of Date or Automatic

Comment: thanks, this works somehow, but I get another error: "DATEVALUE parameter 'QUERY ALL ORDERS date' cannot be parsed to date/time." That's because it's an IMPORTRANGE from a query. I tried to format the  query with "format C ‘yyyy-mm-dd'" but didn't work, this query looks liks this: =QUERY(orders_2019, "SELECT C, W") Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?